# Email Salesforce

Tags: email, object, salesforce

I m with a doubt with email, i have two objects an object call request where which request is related with an account.In the accounti have the email information, and in the"request"  i  have the fields that i need to write my email, so i create an email template where i bring the info from the object request, and now i want to send this email to contact in the account  object.

And how do do a fluxe where it will send the email to my account with the information that i have in que other object.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, the Email Address to which you want to send to is in the Account record and not in a Contact record associated to the Account, yes?

If so, using Standard Workflows, you only need to:

1. Create an Email field on your 'Request' object
2. Create a workflow that populates this new Email field equal to the Account Email Address upon creation/modification
3. Use this Email field to send an email.

Caveat: If the Email Address on the Account has changed, this won't fire off the workflow you created. You would need an Apex Trigger to achieve this.